# Where is the USS Enterprise during the events of Star Trek: Discovery?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

The USS *Enterprise* didn't join the first battle shown in *Star Trek: Discovery*.

> Starships Clarke, Shran, T'Plana Hath, Kerala, Sue, Ride, Earhart, Dana, Edison, and Yeager have dropped out of warp.

Where is the USS Enterprise (any version) during the events of *Star Trek: Discovery*?

Comment: Good question. NCC-1701 was commissioned in 2245, so would have been around for about 10-11 years in May 2256 during the first episode.

Comment: Space is big. You just won't believe how vastly, hugely, mind-mindbogglingly big it is. I mean, you may think it's a long way down the road to the chemist, but that's just peanuts to space.  Basically, it wasn't the entire fleet that answered the Shenzhou's call, but only those ships close enough to respond.  The Shenzhou was right out on the border, so the Enterprise could have been on the far side of the quadrant - too far to respond.

Comment: It is out there!

Comment: It was exploring the Retcon Expanse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### It was on its 5-year mission and was forbidden to participate in the war

In [*Star Trek: Discovery* S02E01 ("Brother")](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Brother_(episode)) we learn that the USS *Enterprise*, under command of Captain Christopher Pike, was on its 5-year mission when the war started (which covers Season 1 of *DIS*).

It was not supposed to participate unless absolutely necessary. Even then, they were far away from the war, so it would still take time to join the war effort.

> PIKE: Missing the war while the *Enterprise* was on its five-year mission, that, uh took a toll on my crew, a toll on Spock. On me, too.
>
> BURNHAM: Even if they had called you back, you were so far away, you wouldn't have made it in time. Starfleet ordered you to stay away for a reason. Enterprise was an instrument of last resort.
>
> [Source](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=star-trek-discovery-2017&episode=s02e01)

Answer (score 26):

## TL;DR - The *Enterprise* was too far away to respond in time

## What do we know?

### About the Battle of the Binary Stars

- We know it occurred in a binary star system 6 light years from Gamma Hydra ([Source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_at_the_Binary_Stars))

### About the *Enterprise*

- The *Enterprise* was under the command of Christopher Pike at the time ('The Menagerie Pt 1', *TOS*)
- During the course of his command, Pike captained the Enterprise to the Rigel, Vega and Talos systems ([Source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(NCC-1701))).

## Let's talk about space...

The Gamma Hydra sector was visited by the *Enterprise* in 2267 in 'The Deadly Years' (*TOS*) and is near the Neutral Zone established after the Earth-Romulan War (*TNG* 'The Defector').

In the map of the explored galaxy commonly shown in various episodes (below), the Neutral Zone is to the far left of the image.  Now, this map is first seen in *Star Trek VI* (2293) ([Source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/File:The_Explored_Galaxy.jpg)), so the *Enterprise* should (barring any strange/unreported instances) have been within the confines of this map.  Looking at the three systems it has been, we see Rigel is 3 cubes from the Neutral Zone in a straight line.  Since in 'Errand of Mercy' (*TOS*) was set in Organia and the territory was disputed between the Federation and Klingons, the border was probably closer to the bottom right edge of the map, which would be even further.

[image: Map of the Known Galaxy]

We also know that a *Constitution* class vessel would take two weeks at maximum cruising speed to reach Rigel from Talos ([Source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Talos_star_group)), which is travelling five 'squares' on the below map.  Add another three 'squares' to travel in a straight line from Rigel to Organia and this increases to just under three weeks.

Another consideration is that the *Enterprise*'s mission was of exploration, so they probably wouldn't have travelled around space at maximum speed, but cruise slowly to explore the galaxy.

## What does it all mean?

So, although Talos isn't the farthest point from where I suspect Gamma Hydra is, it just about is.  Assuming the *Enterprise* was at least an average ship in terms of her engines (sorry Scotty), it would take her just under three days to traverse a 'square' on the map.  **Therefore, all the ships called to the Shenzhou's position must have been inside the 'square' of the Gamma Hydra sector**.  Since the *Enterprise* didn't arrive, ***it mustn't have been anywhere reasonably close.***

Comment: This is an excellent answer.

Comment: This is undermined, somewhat, by the *Enterprise* and *Shenzhou* responding to the same emergency in the prequel novel *Desperate Hours*. Still, it's the best answer we have.

Comment: @Politank-Z by reading the [trivia on Desperate Hours](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Desperate_Hours#Trivia), it seems that: (1) there are other inconsistencies with this novel (like Saru's home planet), and (2) that novel facts get considered _canon_ only if there is screenplay/animation to support it.