# Why did they make another prequel?

Tags: star-trek, behind-the-scenes, star-trek-discovery

***Star Trek: Discovery***, the first new Star Trek television series in 12 years, debuted last week.  As with a number of recent Star Trek efforts, this is a prequel to the *Original Series*, occurring roughly **one decade** prior chronologically.

[image]

The *Original Series*, the *Next Generation*, *Deep Space Nine*, and *Voyager* occur in a chronological sequence that, generally speaking, moves forward (although *TNG*, *DS9*, and *Voyager* overlap to various degrees).  The linear trajectory of Star Trek productions took a sudden shift with the television series *Enterprise*, which was set just over 100 years before *TOS*. This was followed by J.J. Abrams' 2009 film *Star Trek*, which created a new timeline and which followed the characters from *TOS*, but at a time that is also chronologically **one decade** before *TOS*.

Given that the last few interpretations of Star Trek were prequels in one sense or another, I was disappointed that *Discovery* was yet another prequel.  I'd like to know why the showrunners decided to take this direction.  **I haven't been able to find any statements about the rationale.**

That being said, I find it interesting that *Star Trek* (2009) was set in **2255-2258** and *Discovery* is currently set in **2256**, even though they are ostensibly in different timelines — the former in the reboot timeline and the latter supposedly in the original timeline.  Also, one of the showrunners for *Discovery*, Alex Kurtzman, was one of the principal members of the creative team behind the Abrams films.

**Why did the creative staff behind *Discovery* decide to make another prequel?  Does it have anything to do with the fact that *Star Trek* (2009) and *Discovery* are set in roughly the same years?**

Comment: Setting the new show before TOS means no conflict with the Abrams alternate-future films.

Comment: @ThePhoton : The Abrams films aren't an alternate future.  They are an alternate timeline whose events occur *before* *TOS*.  See the chronology outlined in the question.  (If you are referring to the destruction of Romulus in the late 24th Century, then yes, that is something that writers would have to contend with if they made a series set beyond the 24th.)

Comment: @Praxis, they're an alternate future to us because the original timeline is our true future?

Comment: @ThePopMachine : In the future, humanity's last unsolved problem is lens flare.

Comment: At any rate, by setting the new show contemporary with the first Abrams film, they avoid having to maintain continuity between the show and future Abrams films.

Comment: @Praxis, no!  That's the alternate future.  Fortunately, we don't have that problem in the true future.

Comment: They made ten sequel movies and three sequel TV shows. You're mad there aren't more sequels? At least _Discovery_ became a sequel, I guess (spoilers for _Discovery_ season 3 and beyond).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to a 2017 interview with *Entertainment Weekly*, [reported by TrekCore](http://trekcore.com/blog/2017/07/new-ew-issue-details-bryan-fullers-discovery-departure/), *Discovery* creator Brian Fuller's initial pitch had actually been to create an anthology series, in the vein of [*American Horror Story*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Horror_Story); Fuller's proposal would have started in the *Discovery* timeframe, but then progressed through more familiar eras and into the as-yet-unexplored future. It was CBS who wanted to start with just one series:

> Fuller sat with CBS executives to deliver his pitch. It wasn't just for a 'Trek' series but for multiple serialized anthology shows that would begin with the 'Discovery' prequel, journey through the eras of Captain James T. Kirk and Captain Jean-Luc Picard, and then go beyond to a time in 'Trek' that's never been seen before.
>
> *[...]*
>
> CBS countered with the plan of creating a single serialized show and then seeing how it performed.

Although this isn't directly stated, it seems as though Fuller wanted his anthologies to proceed chronologically, so it makes sense to start with the "prequel" series. However, why CBS preferred the prequel over another timeframe isn't recorded here.

The specific timeframe of the series, though, appears to have been coincidental to that of the Abrams films; [Yahoo TV reports](https://www.yahoo.com/tv/star-trek-discovery-panel-000000347.html) on a panel at the 2016 *Star Trek: Mission New York* convention, where writer and producer Nicholas Meyer suggests that the timeframe allowed them some wiggle room to tell stories without trampling all over the canon:

> "It was about finding a space in the chronology to maneuver and create stuff," Meyer says of the decision to pick that particular 10-year gap. "Bryan [Fuller, *Discovery*'s initial creator] didn't want to use the same characters from other series, and a 10-year pre-Kirk thing seemed perfect."

In fairness, it's a pretty good timeframe for avoiding established characters:

- Most (if not all) of the characters of the 90s shows haven't been born yet
- The series is set [firmly](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/170505/31051) in Christopher Pike's command of the NCC-1701 *Enterprise*, so there's limited expectation of seeing any of the TOS cast
- It's long enough after the *Enterprise* series that you wouldn't reasonably expect any of that cast to show up, with the possible exception of T'Pol

Comment: Thanks --- I find this strange for precisely the reason you mention at the end: if they want the ability to "maneuver and create stuff", why not set the show in a completed unsullied future time, post-*Voyager*?  It all seems odd to me.

Comment: @Praxis One thought that occurs is that setting it in the future would make them bound by all the continuity of the 90s shows, while a prequel is less bound by that. Another concern may be that, not terribly long after *Voyager* is when time travel starts being more prominent, which presents its own problems

Comment: Sometimes I think it is the holodeck that killed Star Trek: anything and everything can happen on the holodeck (heck, the Hirogens fought an entire war on one).  The line between reality and simulation is so blurry by the end of *Voyager*, and holography so heavily infused into everything, that it almost seemed like they made *Enterprise* so as not to have to do stories revolving around the holodeck or holograms.

Comment: @Praxis Agreed.  That and the whole "we beat the Borg" thing sort of ruins prospects for good storytelling post-Voyager.  Not saying it would be impossible, but if they're going to follow the "bigger and better than last time" pattern that Hollywood *always follows*, it would be very difficult.  Personally, I wish that New Trek had been a *proper reboot* of the canon, rather than a divergent timeline.

Comment: @Praxis Think you'll find the update interesting; looks like Fuller actually wanted to cover future timeframes as well

Comment: @JasonBaker : Thanks for the update.  It's interesting indeed!  I wonder if they'll actually follow through on Fuller's original vision.  He's still an executive producer, but my impression is that Kurtzman has much more control at this stage.

Comment: @Praxis The TrekCore article goes into that a bit; it seems as though he's been dropped completely, and Fuller himself is pretty adamant that he had little to do with the show we're watching. Doesn't mean they won't use some of his ideas, of course, but at this point anything could happen

Comment: "Most (if not all) of the characters from the 90s shows haven't been born yet." Hmm - at least two would have been (Guinan and the Dax symbiote). Others might have been:Tuvok, Neelix (don't have an idea of the lifespan of his race), possibly Odo (unclear how long he might have been floating around before he was discovered).Oh, and Q, if you want to count him (Guinan wasn't part of the listed cast, but would fall into the same category as Miles O'Brien in TNG and Keiko, Garak, and Dukat in DS9; recurring characters {who, in universe, were around even if not seen]).

Comment: @RDFozz Tuvok is a no (his date of birth is established in season 7 of *Voyager*), and Odo isn't going to show up in any stories (he says he's been taking human form for 30 years). I'm pretty sure Neelix was a fever dream, so that's a third "no"

Comment: @JasonBaker "Not terribly long after Voyager" is when time travel starts being more prominent? They time travel in Star Trek IV, Generations (sort of), First Contact, 2009, and who knows how many television episodes. They can usually think of a new method of time travel in about two sentences of dialog.

Comment: @user45623 I meant that it's when the Federation started having reliable time travel technology; I was on my phone, so not as verbose as I could have been

Comment: I guess Memory Alpha knows how many television episodes (no surprise): http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Time_travel_episodes

Comment: @Praxis Star Trek has _ALWAYS_ been premised around the notion that literally anything can happen when you're exposed to a whole galaxy of wonders. My dad used to (lovingly) refer to TV-based Trek as a form of "variety hour". Every adventure is anything-goes, and all the rules are made to be broken. If that wasn't obvious enough from TOS, they added Q _and_ the Holodeck to Generations and later.

Comment: @user45623 : Believe me, I understand that (and I'm no stranger to Star Trek --- check out my profile).  But sometimes too much of "anything can happen" can make writers scratch their heads about how to move forward.

Comment: Wasn't Spock part of Pikes crew in TOS?

Comment: @Paul : Definitely.

Comment: @Paul [Yes](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/The_Menagerie%2C_Part_I_(episode)). Spock is the most likely past character to make an appearance (and I believe Zachary Quinto had expressed interest at one point), especially considering Michael's relationship with Saren. Whether or not he will is a separate matter

Comment: @JasonBaker, *Sarek

Comment: @ThePopMachine Yeah, him; I've either been playing too much *Mass Effect*, or not nearly enough

Comment: @JasonBaker : I feel as if Fuller and Meyer are holding something back, such as pressure from studio executives who still regard Berman-era Star Trek as having run out of gas and developing too narrow of a fan base.  They likely see the *TOS* era is more profitable at the moment.   At the same time, I can't help but think they must be hoping to cash in on crossovers with *TOS* characters (likely Spock).   I'm accepting this (I think you've found all of the relevant info out there), but if something else turns up later, feel free to revisit this. :-)

Comment: @Paul: Yes. And you have (at least Ensigns) Kirk, Scott, Sulu and Uhura somewhere. And a certain Doctor.

Comment: "setting it in the future would make them bound by all the continuity of the 90s shows, while a prequel is less bound by that" - I don't quite undestand that line of reasoning. Discounting time travel caveats, the past influences the future, but the future doesn't influence the past. Hence, sequels are basically free to add new facets to the universe. Prequels are not free to do so, *they* are bound by the continuity of the 90s shows that limit the set of possible events in the past (e.g. can't blow up Vulcan again).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper My (admittedly poorly-worded) thought was more related to the expectation of heavy continuity in television these days; by setting the show in the future, there's a higher expectation of references to past continuity. But I also agree with you, and I hadn't considered that when I wrote that comment; consider the references to the Borg and the Ferengi on *Enterprise*, for example